# Найти среднее значение элементов массива на языке Java

Tags: java, android, android-sdk

Вот задача. Мне надо использовать **Android project**
В массиве хранятся сведения о количестве осадков, выпавших за каждый день февраля. Определить среднедневное количество осадков в этом месяце.

Я понимаю как решить её логически(нужно сложить все числа в массиве и поделить на размер массива) но написать код не выходит т.к. не помню всех операторов

Можете мне напомнить операторы для выполнения данной задачи?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: 1. Напишите нормальный заголовок. То, что вам нужно решить какую-то задачу известно поумолчанию, т. к. по другому поводу вы бы не задавали вопрос. 2. Что именно у вас вызывает трудности? Или же вы хотите, чтобы кто-нибудь сделал вашу работу вместо вас?

Comment: Операторы вот такие: `=` -- присваивание, `+` -- сложение, `/` -- деление. А если серьезно, то это написано в любом мало-мальски серьезном руководстве по java.

Comment: Если у вас есть конкретные вопросы по реализации, вы всегда получите ответ. А если весь вопрос сводится к "напишите за меня", то увы.

Comment: Операторы в языке Java бывают: арифметические, поразрядные, логические. Работайте. Решение уже Вам написал @Dmitriy Simushev.

Answer (score 3):

Алгоритм решения задачи выглядит следующим образом:

1. Обойти массив, просуммировав все его значения в переменную
2. Найти количество элементов массива
3. Разделить, значение, полученное в п. 1 на значение из п. 2.

Код писать не буду принципиально, поскольку задача явно учебная и должна решаться вами самостоятельно.